# How to sort Laravel Eloquent ORM objects?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

For example, we have a model flight having 3 fields:

- created_at: the time when the flight created
- name: the name of the flight
- score: the score of the flight

So I write that:

```
$flights = App\Flight::orderBy('created_at');
```

I get some `$flight` objects ordered by `create_time`. So I will change the name of flight by `create_time` to `first_flight`, `second_flight` and so on...

But I want to display `$flights` sorted by score. So I have to sort `$flights` by score, but I have no idea how to achieve that.

So my question is, how to sort Eloquent ORM objects by a field(in my example, it's `score`)?

Comment: @theomessin Then I will have `$flights1 = App\Flight::orderBy('created_at');`, `$flights2 = App\Flight::orderBy('score');`. I just want to have one `$flights` and sort in place...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get a collection:

```
$flights = App\Flight::all();
```

And then sort it with [`sortBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-sortby) or [`sortByDesc()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-sortbydesc) without hitting DB:

```
$filghts->sortBy('created_at');
....
$filghts->sortBy('score');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want order by multiple column in same time use this

```
App\Flight::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->orderBy('score', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```